# Excel invisible question mark

Tags: excel, vba

I have an extracted information from a system into an Excel file.
The names "Leone" seem the same but Excel recognize it differently.

Leone

​Leone

The length of the string is not the same, and if I check the value with VBA an invisible ? is the first character.

Could you help me how to get rid of the invisible characters?

[image]

Comment: if you do SUBSTITUTE ? with ""  and add a TRIM does that make a difference?

Comment: From the image, it seems like a zero-width character

Comment: I have already tried: SUBSTITUTE, TRIM, CLEAN functions

Comment: FWIW - A `=UNICODE("​Leone")` shows it is code 8203.

Comment: @Erika `=SUBSTITUTE("​Leone","​","")` does seem to work.  (where that first `"​"` is including the character (even though you can't see it :D)

Comment: I guess you could use the Excel formula `=IF(UNICODE(A2)>255,RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),A2)`

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of all invisible `?` you may try this.

```
Sub CleanUnicode()
    Dim n As Long, strClean As String, strChr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to data sheet
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:A10")      'change A1:A10 to working range
        strClean = cel.Value
        For n = Len(strClean) To 1 Step -1
            strChr = Mid(strClean, n, 1)
            If AscW(strChr) = 8203 Then     '? is unicode character 8203
                strClean = Replace(strClean, strChr, "")
            End If
        Next
        cel.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(strClean)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Instead of `If AscW(strChr) = 8203 Then` you can also use `If AscW(strChr) > 255 Then`.

**EDIT 1 :** As per the suggestion of @YowE3K. Assuming you only have `Unicode 8203` in cells to be replaced.

```
Sub CleanUnicode()
    Dim n As Long, strClean As String, strChr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to data sheet
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:A10")      'change A1:A10 to working range
        cel.Value = Replace(cel.Value, ChrW(8203), "")
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Got this from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/669958-removing-hidden-chr-within-text-chr63.html).

Comment: @YowE3K - Yes, provided that there is just single occurrence of `?` in the the cell as stated by the OP, `cel.Value = Replace(cel.Value, ChrW(8203), "")` can be used followed by `Exit For`.

Comment: @YowE3K - I'll be glad.

Comment: BTW - Congrats on reaching 10k!  That must have been about a week ago and I have only just noticed.

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you, Reached 10k around 8-10 days back. Was away from work for past 4-5 days. Next Is your turn.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is strange - this is how chrome renders the HTML from the question:

[image]

This is a workaround, that checks the characters of the string and builds a new one if one of them is equal to 63. Pretty much like a simple replace function:

```
Public Function removeInvisible(rngRange As Range) As String

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = 1 To Len(rngRange)
        If AscW(Mid(rngRange, cnt, 1)) <> 8203 Then
            removeInvisible = removeInvisible & Mid(rngRange, cnt, 1)
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. The OP is asking for removing invisible characters (not visualising them)

Comment: And I didn't downvote, but I don't think the character is actually invisible in Excel - just zero-width.  So setting the colour doesn't really help - it just becomes a black character that is zero-width.

Comment: @YowE3K - how do you make a zero-width character in Excel?

Comment: Not sure, but copying the string from the question into Excel seems to be one way.

Comment: Unfortunately, checking for 63 using `Asc` will pick up normal `"?"` characters.  You'll need to check for an `AscW` of 8203.

Comment: @YowE3K - yup, true.

Answer (score 0):

If the text has come from a copy/paste it might have taken in some other non printable characters.
These might be displayed in the VBA editor as ? which is often the way that unicode characters are rendered when the font does not support them.

I would try the formula
`=CODE(LEFT(A3,1))` in one of the cells to see what the Unicode code point of the invisible character was.

If it turns out to be a non ascii chat then you could write a macro to strip out the characters that are problematic based on their code values.

Comment: `=UNICODE("​Leone")` shows it is code 8203.  (You should be able to copy/paste that formula from my comment and see the result in Excel.)

Answer (score 0):

To remove multiple occurrences of non-ascii characters from all cells of your range you can use this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim temparray() As String
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim lcol As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    'set your last row and column
    lrow = 5
    lcol = 5

    ReDim temparray(1 To lrow, 1 To lcol)
    Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, lcol))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    counter = 0

    For i = 1 To lrow
        For j = 1 To lcol
            temparray(i, j) = regEx.Replace(myrange.Cells(i, j).Value, "")
          counter = counter + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    myrange.Value = temparray

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```