# VBA Conditional Operator returning incorrect result in String Comparison

Tags: string, vba, list, excel, conditional-statements

I was unable to really word the title in its entirety without cluttering the textbox. Anyway, I can't seem to find an answer to my issue. I'm reading a bullet point from a cell in Excel with VBA. Once it's read, I then compare it to a list of characters and format accordingly.

When VBA reads said bullet point a "?" is returned. So, I attempted to compare it with a string variable with the value of "?". The conditional operator does not compute correctly and it returns a false.

Language: VBA

Software: 
Microsoft Excel 2016

Cell formatting:
Tahoma 10

String:
●   Deliverable

The value returned to iBullet is "?" when hovering over the syntax in the debugging environment

```
Code:
   Dim BulletPointBlue string
   BulletPointBlue = "?"

   iBullet = Left(Deliverable, 1)

   ElseIf Chr(iBullet) = BulletPointBlue Then

   Format Cell
```

I figured maybe VBA debugging window is masking the value with a "?" and so therefore it's not equivalent to the "?" character. I can't really find any information to reach a conclusion so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try in immediate window when it is the activecell: `?Asc(ActiveCell.Value)` and see what ascii value it is then you can do something with it. This out of range character to "?" happens when the language of the text does not match the language of non-unicode programs setting in Windows.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, `if asc(left(deliverable,1))=63 then...`

Comment: @PatricK I think the OP should use `?AscW(ActiveCell.Value)` to check for the correct **UniCode** number - it will probably return 63 with just an `Asc`.  (It's probably UniCode 9679, but I wouldn't guarantee that.)

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K, keep forgetting the UniCode one. OP: To reverse (unicode number to character), use `ChrW(#Long)`.

Comment: @PatricK I only managed to remember it due to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46724599/6535336) which I came across about a week ago.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware At the moment that won't work because `BulletPointBlue` has been set to be `"?"`.  It will **probably** work once `BulletPointBlue` is set to be `ChrW(9679)`, but we can't be sure until the OP confirms what the Unicode character is at the start of the string.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes I see. Sorry I was tired and I guess I missed the point of the post.

Comment: Hey, everyone! Thanks for all these helpful responses. I wasn't able to get the ascw value from the cell's parsed string with any of the functions above. Maybe my syntax was wrong? Either way I used a workaround and instead I'm using another column to reference these cells and produce the Unicode value (9679 as YowE3K stated) using the =UNICODE() function. This has fixed my issue! Thanks again!